# Should we make a new tag called 'rEFInd' in replacement of 'rEFIt'?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I have been asking a few questions lately about rEFInd and have had to use the tag [refit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refit).

Should we make an updated tag for rEFInd since rEFIt is outdated now? If we shouldn't then why?

This will also help to distinguish between the old rEFIt and the new rEFInd.

Here are the links to the questions:

- [Uninstall rEFInd 0.8-3.7 on Yosemite](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/188190/uninstall-refind-0-8-3-7-on-yosemite)
- [Install rEFInd on another partition](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/188401/install-refind-on-another-partition)

Comment: If you want to link to the questions I could see making both temporarily while we sort out what we'll do eventually.

Comment: @bmike Edited my question to include my links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My vote would be to merge both to [efi](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/efi) or some other tag further up the hardware chain.

What are your thoughts of tagging these utilities more on what they do (replace/interface with EFI) than what the program du jour is called?

Comment: I would say that's a good idea since refit and rEFInd are both to do with the EFI boot-loader. Or could we make a boot-loader tag since it is what boots the computer?